# 500 Server Error on GAE - MySQLdb not loaded

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, mysql-python

I get a 500 Server Error while uploading my app on GAE. It works perfectly fine locally with dev_appserver with SETTINGS_MODE='prod'.

Based on the logs, it cannot find MySQLdb on GAE. It does not make sense to me.

Help!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 49, in load_middleware
    mod = import_module(mw_module)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Comment: On GAE? This problem happens only on the Google App Engine server and not locally.

Comment: Just figured the solution. app.yaml needs the following libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"

Comment: you should answer this question yourself then if you have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is fairly simple. Add the following lines in the app.yaml file:

libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"

Details can be found on the page

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql